# Is there a RocksDB java JNI implementation that supports compression?

Tags: java, rocksdb

Seems like the rocksdb jni for Windows doesn't come linked with any of the compression methods. When any compression method is set, and I try to run my project, I get the following:

```
org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Compression type [COMPRESSIONTYPE] is not linked with the binary.
```

Can someone explain how I can at least get something like XPRESS or SNAPPY?

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
    <version>5.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

CODE:

```
options.setCompressionType(CompressionType.XPRESS_COMPRESSION);
```

Comment: It seems you have to build the native package yourself to enable compression. From [here (scroll to the bottom)](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Building-on-Windows): *NOTE: The build options below include -DXPRESS=1 which enables Microsoft XPRESS compression. This requires Windows 10 or newer to work reliably and is not backwards compatible with older versions of Windows. At present we build RocksJava releases without XPRESS.* - My understanding is that you need to build it yourself enabling that option

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Any chance there is a build with any OTHER baked-in compression? (SNAPPY?)

Comment: If you look at the very bottom of the linked page you'll see a build command, I believe that is the one which enables you to choose which options you want to activate. For snappy, I see `-DSNAPPY=1` which might be what you're looking for

Comment: Built, but the output doesn't include anything that resembles a jar + dlls that I can simply add to my project. Any thoughts?